# Как исправить ошибку в боте , что не так?

Tags: python, aiogram

Вообщем проблема такая, самый простой бот, и выдает такую оишбку не видит start_polling хотя прописан и допом установлен через pip install start polling
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `pip install start polling`, эм? start_polling - функция бота, а не модуль. Покажите текстом минимальный пример с проблемой

Comment: А что такое `executor`? Судя по ошибке это модуль, у которого нет такого метода `start_pooling`. Код и полный стрек-трейс ошибки должны быть прямо в вопросе, в виде текста, а не скриншота.

Comment: Покажите импорты

Comment: from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
import logging
import executor

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вы неправильно импортируете модули.
Вот пример, для последнее версии aiogram'a.
У вас так же? Игнорируйте `import config`, там просто токен.

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

import config

bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Старт")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Я токен напрямую подключаю без конфига

Comment: Я рад этому, но я спрашивал про другое.

Comment: from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
Модули да именно так

Comment: покажите установленные пакеты в python packages

Comment: И добавьте весь код текстом

Comment: И чисто ради интереса попробуйте вставить мой код, заменив на свой токен

Comment: Закрывайте вопрос, нажав на галочку слева от ответа

Answer (score 0):

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage


bot = Bot(token='ВАШ ТОКЕН')
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Старт")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Вот исправленный код.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]